# Google Analytics API - authenticate from sql server using t-sql

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Is it possible to connect to google analytics api using only t-sql?
I'm trying to find a solution unfortunately without success.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Im not enough of a T-sql expert, but i dont think so. You would need make HTTP POST and GET Calls and be able to parse the json that's returned.   I created a SSIS task once for it that worked but purely t-sql i dont think so.

Comment: Have you looked into using Ole?

Comment: What do you mean using Ole? 
Regarding your before comment maybe do have example how to use ssis task? I tried find solutions on your website and YT but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @DaImTo you mean OLE objects. I tried but without success. I don't know how to create correct GET for acces token

Comment: This will walk you though how to create an access token https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w.  Its with curl but its still HTTP

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://zappysys.com/blog/import-google-analytics-data-sql-server-reporting-etl/